# Battery not charging

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, charging

I think I went through all "battery is not charging" posts already.

1. SMC Reset: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201295
2. Battery Health does not have a button "Manage Battery Longevity" https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211094
3. There is not "charge to full now" when clicking on the battery icon
4. I tried unplug/replug, reboot, searched all settings

and yet:

[image]

None of the above worked. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Which MBP are you trying to charge with which wall adapter? If your MBP draws e.g. 80Watts but your power supply only outputs 60 then your battery will drain.

Comment: @X_841 I will try with my 96Watts adapter later then... You might be right, the same adapter works for my wife's MacBook Air, so I did not think of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check the wattage on the adapter. If you have one that’s supplying less than is needed, the Mac runs and charges slowly or not at all.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700

Other times, a unit needs service when it’s not functioning correctly. But let’s first establish if the battery can take any charge before you run a more full test of the charging circuitry. One SMC reset a week is plenty, so that’s off the table now - good work there.

1. Shut down the OS while power remains connected
2. Wait 30 minutes
3. See if you get meaningful charge above 11%

If you want to save a trip to the store and can’t get remote troubleshooting service from Apple, I would also consider using different cables and power sources if you get no benefit from 30 minutes of charge while off.

You seem to have covered the other easy fixes than using known good power source and cables. My hunch is your adapter isn’t providing enough power for when the machine runs, but we will need some more data to conclude that (and that’s what Apple troubleshooting will also helo you determine).

Comment: I have tried several cables, and tested those cables on other devices, including other macbooks. I will try to charge it while it is down, this indeed usually works. but it is annoying, in fact just closing the lid is often enough. But it is very annoying, for example when watching netflix, the battery keeps going down slowly even if plugged in. I have to stop using my computer to recharge it... How is this a feature?

Comment: I don’t even know what’s happening  @user2346536  - are you providing new day that the charger works to fully charge the device in 2-3 hours when off yet can’t keep up with the unit when it’s running?

Comment: actually X_841 might be right. I charges when sleeping or off, but it is very slow, normally I leave it for the night, so I had no idea how long it took, but after checking, it charged from 10% to 36% in about 4h when off. It might be my power adapter, and the MacBookAir of my wife might require lower wattage than my pro...

Comment: That happens at work ALL THE TIME - people are in a meeting and swap adapters, then the Pro is starved for power. Once you get the right wattage adapter on the Pro it should be happy again.